# Ansible Unsupported Parameters for using handler

Tags: ansible, linux

I'm trying to run a ansible task but I keep getting an error.

This is the play I want to run:

```yaml
- name: use of handlers
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: install packages
      yum:
        name: httpd
        state: latest
        notify: restart package
  handlers:
    - name: restart package
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: restarted
```

But this is the error that ansible gives me:

> fatal: [serverb.local]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.dnf) module: notify. Supported parameters include: allowerasing, allow_downgrade, name (pkg), enablerepo, disable_excludes, conf_file, list, disable_plugin, installroot, enable_plugin, disable_gpg_check, download_dir, update_cache (expire-cache), releasever, state, nobest, bugfix, install_weak_deps, update_only, autoremove, exclude, download_only, cacheonly, security, lock_timeout, skip_broken, disablerepo, validate_certs, install_repoquery."}

Answer (score 3):

The indentation is wrong. Correct syntax is

```yaml
     - name: install packages
       yum:
         name: httpd
         state: latest
       notify: restart package
```

The error says it:

```
"Unsupported parameters for (ansible.legacy.dnf) module: notify.
```

*notify* is not a parameter of the module [*dnf*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dnf_module.html#ansible-builtin-dnf-module-manages-packages-with-the-dnf-package-manager) or [*yum*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html#ansible-builtin-yum-module-manages-packages-with-the-yum-package-manager). It is a [*playbook keyword*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) that can be applied to a block or a task. In the above case, it must be indented as a task keyword. See [Notifying handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#notifying-handlers).